# Special character returns wrong codepoint

Tags: javascript, utf-8, special-characters, diacritics, unicode-normalization

We have a problem with reading special characters from our database. We have character encoding configured as UTF-8 everywhere and the database seemingly stores all characters fine. For example we have a word with an `é` and it looks all good on screen. Also in the JSON response objects the character looks fine (with the accent) and it even seemingly works when we copy to clipboard and paste. But when we do strict comparison `é === é` we get `false` as a result. Turns out the stored `é` returns charcode 101 which is `e` without the accent (not [the expected char code 233](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm)).

- `é` = [code 233](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm)
- `é` = [code 101](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0065/index.htm)

I will demonstrate the problem even here in this code snippet: both characters look the same but one of them outputs `233` and the other `101`.

```js
// é = 233
// é = 101

console.log("é".charCodeAt());
console.log("é".charCodeAt());
```

Why is this happening?
Apparently the fact that the character is an `e` with an accent is stored somehow correctly in the database (it looks correct), but not outputted as expected to the client. How can we enforce that the character is read correctly as an `e` with an accent as `é` (code 233)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize

The second `é` is actually 2 characters: the `e` and [a combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) for the accent. The solution is to call `.normalize()` and then after that I can strict compare.

```js
// é = 233 (one single char)
// é = 101 (actually 2 characters, first is "e")

console.log("é".length);
console.log("é".length);

// Normalizing will return char 233 and then strict comparison will work.
console.log("é".normalize() === "é");
```

Comment: If [Unicode normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) is new to you then don't blindly use it, but also ask yourself up to which point you don't want to manipulate original data. Also have a read read about [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack), since [latin `A` != greek `Α` != cyrillic `А`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#Ancestors_and_siblings_in_other_alphabets).

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks for your input. We had quite some discussion in the team exactly regarding the issues you are lifting and then we also talked about Latin vs Cyrillic vs Greek chars (didn't seem relevant to mention it in the post here since it was specific about combining characters).  In our case normalizing seems the right approach since the accents "mean" the same, but the difference comes from the input method.